# How to save picture taken by camera to local application folder?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-activity, camera

How would I go about saving an image to a folder within the app? I want to eventually allow users to take pictures and upload and allow others to "rate it." I'm new to android, so I'm sorry if this is very basic. This is what I have so far.

public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
            Intent picture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //MainActivity.this.startActivity(picture);

             startActivityForResult(picture, 1);
             onActivityResult(1, 1, picture){

             }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving it elsewhere and then attempting to move it?

You could write a file in which saves it to its original directory and then will move into the one that you wish to do automatically.

You obviously already have enough skills to relocate a file within that executable.

Sorry if im not much help im brand new to the whole stackoverflow community.

hope i helped you though!

Comment: I actually have no idea how to save the file at all. I'm not sure what to really do with the Result activity.

Comment: It's an app I'm developing, if that's what you mean? I haven't released it yet. Still has a long ways to go.

Comment: ok well is it an app thats going to be web published or something that you just want to use with people like your friends. Because if you are going to publish it to the web then it will try to debug some of the stuff for you and give you trouble shooting help but if its just with your friends then we're in the same boat.

Comment: I'd like to eventually publish it haha.

Answer (score 0):

read this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
hope this will help you..

Comment: seems helpful, I'm just having trouble finding which line to actually put down my "images" folder onto.. i feel like im missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code. Explanations are after the code

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/");
else
    cameraFolder= StatusUpdate.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "picture_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/" + imageFileName);
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, 1);
```

What this code essentially does is:

- Creates a folder with the name provided where it reads
  **YOUR_FOLDER_NAME** (Change this to your convenience)
- The `picture_" + timeStamp + ".jpg` ensures that multiple images will
  be stored in the folder of your choice, each with a new timestamp.
  Naturally, the timestamp will be the current time.
- The `initialURI` is globally defined to help you process the Image
  taken later. For example, displaying it in an `ImageView`

Comment: How do i stop the pic from being saved in the common camera picture folder